# input data normalized to zero mean and unit standard deviation

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A and I want normalized to zero mean and unit standard deviation. This expression is : A=(A-mean)/std

But how to implement this in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: The best way to do this is to find a good book or tutorial on programming in MATLAB, going through them to understand the basics, and then searching the MATLAB documentation for "mean" and "standard deviation".

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`zscore`** function. for an example consider `A=[1 2 3 4 5]` you can use below commands

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
n = zscore(A);
```

output will be

```
ans =

-1.2649   -0.6325         0    0.6325    1.2649
```

**for a matrix** first you need to reshape matrix consider below example

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5;6 7 8 9 10]
[n,m]=size(A);            
out = reshpae(zscore( A(:) ), n, m)
```

output will be

```
out =

-1.4863   -1.1560   -0.8257   -0.4954   -0.1651
 0.1651    0.4954    0.8257    1.1560    1.4863
```